# Remove special char from string in C under Linux

Tags: c, linux, string, multibyte, widechar

Using C in Linux, how can I remove character `€` (or any other "specific" non ASCII character - passed as a parameter to the function -) from a string?

I have tried with:

```
void remove_all_chars(char* str, char c) {
    char *pr = str, *pw = str;
    while (*pr) {
        *pw = *pr++;
        pw += (*pw != c);
    }
    *pw = '\0';
}
```

but I get:

> :warning: multi-character character constant.

Should I convert before the string in wide char something like

```
wchar_t wsAux[100];
remove_all_chars(wsAux, "A€bcd", 100);
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: What encoding is the input? Also, "remove" meaning make the string shorter?

Comment: I understand what you are doing with pointers (it's quite smart) but I can't figure out if it is totally safe. I'd rather allocate a new string and recopy only valid chars...

Comment: @Coconop It's safe, as the "write" pointer will always be equal or less than the "read" pointer. Try it out on paper.

Comment: I have to stop crushing my brain on screen, paper told me it was good indeed ^^

Comment: This question revolves around exactly how the text is encoded. It will be `\x80` in Windows-1252, `\xe2\x82\xac` in UTF-8, `\x20\xac` in UCS2/UTF-16 or `\x00\x00\x20\xac` in UCS4/UTF-32.

Comment: @Phylogenesis could you give me an example ?

Comment: If you strictly want to remove non-ASCII characters, then just remove any byte with the top bit set... Granted, that might leave some additional unintended junk from the second and later bytes of multi-byte characters, depending on the source encoding, but without getting more specific about exactly what you need, it's a start...

Comment: @famedoro Yes: [here](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: If encoding is UTF8 `void remove_all_nonASCII(char* str) { char *pr = str, *pw = str; while (*pr) { *pw = *pr++; pw += ((*pw & ~7F) == 0); } *pw = '\0'; }`

Comment: Basically, you can't expect to fit `€` in a `char`.

Comment: @DavidLeonard But you can, sometimes... e.g. ISO-8859 encoding with unsigned chars...

Comment: @chux Thanks for your example, but I want to remove only € or other specified char.

Comment: @Phylogenesis an example in C ? I dont found it in http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: @famedoro My point is, without knowing the encoding of the text, You, I, nor anyone else can tell you exactly how to remove it. Any character could be encoded as multiple different bytestrings.

Comment: @famedoro  You did not show how you called `remove_all_chars()`.  Post did show the compiler message albeit without indicating exactly what line caused it.  Please post the _exact_ code.  Was it like: `char s[] = "A€bcd"; remove_all_chars(s, '€');`?

Comment: @chux Using char s[] = "A€bcd"; remove_all_chars(s, '€'); I have  warning: multi-character character constant
warning: overflow in implicit constant conversion

Comment: @Phylogenesis I'm using linux with gcc without any locale settings, then I think I using UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried:

```
void removeSubstring(char *s,const char *toremove)
{
  while( s=strstr(s,toremove) )
   memmove(s,s+strlen(toremove),1+strlen(s+strlen(toremove)));
}
```

from [Removing substring from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833347/removing-substring-from-a-string) and it works.

In this way then € symbol is treated as string, in fact it occupy 3 bytes ( try strlen("€") )!

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
#include<stdio.h>
void remove_all_chars(char* str) {
    char *pr = str, *pw = str;
    while (*pr) {
    if(isascii(*pr))
    {
        //printf("%c: is ascii char \n", *pr);
        *pw = *pr;
        pw++;
    }
    pr++;
    }
    *pw = '\0';
}

main()
{

    char str[100] = "asÄ—df";
    remove_all_chars(str);
    printf("%s\n",str);

}
```

Comment: isprint removes non printable things.   If you are interested in keeping all of the ASCII codes, consider the isascii function call.

Comment: @user207064 thanks for your example, but I want to specify the character to be removed.

Comment: you can replace if(isascii(*pr)) with

Answer (score 0):

I *guess* you are doing something like

```
remove_all_chars(some_string, 'A€bcd');
```

Note that you are using multiple characters in a character literal. This is not allowed, except as an extension to the compiler. And most likely will not work as you expect.

Instead pass the characters you want to remove as a *string*:

```
remove_all_chars(some_string, "A€bcd");
```

Of course with the proper modification to the `remove_all_chars` function.

Comment: No, if I've used remove_all_chars(field, "A€bcd"); I've  warning: passing argument 2 of ‘remove_all_chars’ makes integer from pointer without a cast. I also want to remove only 1 character, not a string.

Comment: @famedoro That's why I added the last sentence, that you need to modify the function accordingly.

Comment: I also want to remove only 1 character, not a string.

Comment: The modification @JoachimPileborg is talking about is to compare each element of the string of "forbidden chars": for each `char c` in `"A€bcd"` string ensure `(*pw != c)`

Comment: @famedoro You have to check against each character in the string.