# how to cut out a substring from a string in c

Tags: c, string

Is there any way which i can cut out a sub string of a given string?
I mean, let's say that my string contains friend's names separated by `_$_` and I want to cut out a friend name from that string, is there any function to do so?
Example: `mike tull_$_tom cruise_$_noy elias` and i want to cut out `tome cruise`.

P.S: I don't know the exact place of the sub string and of course I can use `strstr`, but is there a built function to do so?

Comment: There is no single function that accomplishes this task in the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [strtok](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) to split your string. Note that it modifies the string you pass as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Possible Duplicate :[Removing substring from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833347/removing-substring-from-a-string)

Find the position of starting and ending '$' in your string which seperates the name you need (or any other separator), then use strcpy to copy the string from starting '$' to ending '$' with string length (position of end - position of start +1) to the variable you wish to use.

or use strtok as suggested. View this for documentation on the same: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm