# Remove substrings from a C-style string "in place" in C++ code

Tags: c++

I had an interview task to remove substring from a current string without using string functions or additional memory...I tried just with `strlen` but didn't find the way to change it in place...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char * str = "this that there";
    char * substr = "th";
    removeSubstr(str,substr); 
    cout<<str;  //should be now "is at ere"

    return 0;
}
void removeSubstr(char * str, const char * substr){
}
```

Comment: You're not actually in the interview right now, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Removing substring from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833347/removing-substring-from-a-string)

Comment: c/c++ is not a language. Pick a language please.

Comment: This question is asked extremely often. There are many many answers on the internet.

Comment: Can't be done. `"this that there"` is an array of `const char`. You can't modify the characters in it. In fact, assigning it to a `char*` is now illegal; it used to produce undefined behavior.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: @PeteBecker if so you could do it with `const_cast`.

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин -- no. When an object is, in fact, `const`, casting away `const` and attempting to modify the object results in undefined behavior. In particular, string literals are often stored in read-only memory, and trying to write to a string literal will crash the program.

Comment: @PeteBecker read-only memory? cd-rom may be If you mean CS data you could not have(OS-provided) pointer to it.

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин -- I'm referring to memory that the program is not allowed to write to. Most operating systems support read-only access within a program; it's used to protect data that should not be modified.

Comment: yeah `const_cast` wont work there. Idk about protected mode and paging, there is read-only attribute there but it's related to whole page or smth like  that. Dos only has it in cs

Comment: Like @PeteBecker said, you can't do that unless you change the declaration to `char str[] = "this that there";` because then it is memory that you own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Since you remove characters from the original string, the string is **shrinking, so you do not need additional space**. You just have to copy characters from a higher index (source) to a lower index (destination).
- If the source index points to a position that **starts with the searched substring, you must skip it.**
- The skip function simply **compares the beginning of the source string against the substring**, and returns the source (if it does not start with the substring) or the source plus the length of substring (if it starts with the substring).

**[Demo](https://www.ideone.com/erEhHe)**

```
#include <iostream>

char* skip_if( char* s, const char* ss )
{
  char* p = s;
  const char* pp = ss;
  while( *p == *pp && *p )
    p++, pp++;
  return *pp ? s : p;
}

void remove( char* s, const char* ss )
{
  char *ps = s; // source
  char *pd = s; // destination
  while( *ps )
  {
    ps = skip_if( ps, ss );
    *pd++ = *ps++;
  }
  *pd = 0;
}

int main()
{
  using namespace std;

  char str[] = "this that there this that there";
  const char* substr = "th";
  remove( str, substr );

  cout << str;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The string functions exist for a reason.  If you are not to use them, can you create them from scratch?

If so, here is my solution to the problem.  Very educational to write custom string functions with the const requirements.

As mentioned in the comments, this won't work unless the string passed in can be modified, so I made it a non-constant string.

Let me know if this meets the interview challenge:

```c++
#include <iostream>

bool myStrnCmp(char *str1, const char *str2, int len) {
    char *cptr1 = (char *) str1;
    char *cptr2 = (char *) str2;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (*(cptr1 + i) != *(cptr2 + i))
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int mystrlen(const char* str) {
    int i = 0;
    while(*(str + i) != '\0')
        i++;
    return i;
}

int findSubStr(char *str, const char *substr) {
    int position = 0;
    int len = mystrlen(substr);

    while(*(str + position) != '\0') {
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            if (myStrnCmp(str + position + i, substr, len))
                return position + i;
        }
        ++position;
    }
    return -1;
}

void myStrCpy(char *str, const char *substr) {
    memmove(str, substr, mystrlen(substr) + 1);

}

void removeSubstr(char *str, const char *substr) {
    int position = findSubStr(str, substr);
    while(position >= 0) {
        myStrCpy(str + position, str+position+mystrlen(substr));
        position = findSubStr(str, substr);
    }

}


int main() {
    char str[]{"this that there"};
    char* substr = "th";
    removeSubstr(str,substr);
    std::cout<<str;  //should be now "is at ere"

    return 0;
}
```